# Unable to stop an existing gcp instance using ansible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

I am trying to stop an existing gcp instance using ansible. Here is the playbook I am using:

```yaml
- name: Stop an instance
  hosts: virtualmachines
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - name: Stop an instance
     google.cloud.gcp_compute_instance:
        project: <project name>
        machine_type: <type>
        name: <name>
        zone: <zone>
        service_account_file: <file_path>
        auth_kind: "serviceaccount"
        status: stopped
        state: present
        deletion_protection: true
```

When I run the playbook, I get the following response, but the instance does not stop.

```
PLAY [Stop an instance] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Stop an instance] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [vm01]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
vm01                       : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: According to the documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_module.html did you try "status: stopping"

Comment: that does not work

Comment: are you able to stp the instance through cli 
`gcloud compute instances stop INSTANCE_NAME --zone=ZONE`

Comment: have you tried with status: TERMINATED or status: STOPPING (since you dont want to terrminate and only stop the instance), please make sure they are in uppercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `status: STOPPING` to get this working

```
---
- name: Stop an instance
  hosts: virtualmachines
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - name: Stop an instance
     google.cloud.gcp_compute_instance:
        project: <project name>
        machine_type: <type>
        name: <name>
        zone: <zone>
        service_account_file: <file_path>
        auth_kind: "serviceaccount"
        status: STOPPING
        deletion_protection: true
```

valid choices for status include: “PROVISIONING”, “STAGING”, “RUNNING”, “STOPPING”, “SUSPENDING”, “SUSPENDED”, “TERMINATED”

as per the [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_module.html#status)

Comment: status: TERMINATED works